# Why is the new version of libstdc++ based on inheritance rather than implements it in one class?

Tags: c++, g++, std, libstdc++

I was studying the source code of libstdc++ recently and found that the 2.9 version of libstdc++ is implemented in one class, and other tool classes are composed internally, but the new version of libstdc++ has a complicated inheritance structure, and I don’t quite understand the necessary of this implementation.

For example, the previous vector contains three pointers：start,finish and end_of_storage，but now it's structure is as follows:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "source code of STL"   and "2.9 version" ?

Comment: I mean GUN C++ 2.9 and the new version  refers to GUN C++ 4.9

Comment: STL is a relic of the past.  Since C++ 11 (and maybe even in C++98) there's no more STL, it's just the C++ runtime libraries.  As for the inheritance question - that's an implementation detail of that particular compiler.

Comment: But if I had to guess, there are template specializations for std::vector such as `vector<bool>` which stores elements as bits, not bytes.  In that case, the common base class can manage the collection fundamentals, but the specialized class can handle the mapping of index values to individual bits in an array, not just an array offset.

Comment: I was learning the implementation details of STL when I had this question

Comment: My answer still stands for STL as well.

Comment: I think what you said makes sense

Comment: One of the reasons for this complicated inheritance - [empty base class optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo). If an allocator is an empty class, which it typically is, we don't want it make a vector object itself larger. An empty data member contributes at least 1 byte into the object size and typically more due to alignment, so we can't just add an allocator data member. In C++20 we'll have `[[no_unique_address]]` but that's still an optional optimization, afaik.

Comment: Simple check: the STL has a container named `hash_set`. The C++ standard library has a container named `unordered_set`. Which library are you dealing with? If the implementation you are looking at does not implement `hash_set`, please edit your question to accurately describe what you are looking at. When you do so, keep in mind that there is no canonical implementation of the C++ standard library -- different compilers may use implementations written by different groups, each with their own versioning scheme.

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you post the link of source code.